# Yii : Undefined variable: nama_unit_kerja

Tags: variables, yii, frameworks, undefined

I need help. when i open my index it shows that the nama_unit_kerja variable is not defined..
But i've put them in the SiteController. How can i fix this.

This is my SiteController code :

```
public function actionIndex()
{   
    //$this->layout = "//layouts/adr/main";
    /* $browser = Yii::app()->browser->isMobile();
    echo ($browser?'mobile':'not mobile'); exit; */

    @session_start();
    Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = array('site/index');
    $lang = 'en';
    if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])) $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    $this->layout='//layouts/erp/index';
    $modelUnitKerja=new UnitKerja('searchKapTarReal');
    $modelUnitKerja->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

    $modelJenisKegiatan=new JenisKegiatan('searchKapTarReal');
    $modelJenisKegiatan->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

    //var_dump($_POST);exit;
    if ((isset($_POST['unitKerja'])) or (isset($_POST['year']))){
        if(empty($_POST['unitKerja'])){
            $unitKerja = 0;
        } else {
            $unitKerja = $_POST['unitKerja'];
            $nama_unit_kerja = UnitKerja::model()->findByAttributes(array("id"=>$_POST['unitKerja']))->nama_unit_kerja;
        }
        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $year_nm = Year::model()->findByAttributes(array("id"=>$_POST['year']))->year;
    }else{
        $unitKerja = 0;
        $year = Year::model()->findByAttributes(array("year"=>date('Y')))->id;
        $year_nm = date('Y');
    }

    $this->render('index',array(
        'mJenisKegiatan'=>$modelJenisKegiatan,
        'mUnitKerja'=>$modelUnitKerja,
        'unitKerja'=>$unitKerja,
        'nama_unit_kerja'=>$nama_unit_kerja,
        'year'=>$year,
        'year_nm'=>$year_nm,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$nama_unit_kerja = UnitKerja::model()->findByAttributes(array("id"=>$_POST['unitKerja']))->nama_unit_kerja;
```

hopefully you are getting this error on this line because you are trying to access the property of yii base. 
you can use it like

```
$nama_unit_kerja = UnitKerja::model()->findByAttributes(array("id"=>$_POST['unitKerja']));
$nama_unit_kerja=$nama_unit_kerja->$nama_unit_kerja;
```

Comment: it's still says that nama_unit_kerja is not defined.